# A day in the bug (?)

Tags: bug, timestamps

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-lebesgue-space/51503#51503) was asked on July 14, 2011. But [Jesse Madnick's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/39273/34397) has a timestamp showing that he answered on May 15, 2011. *How*?

[image]
[image]

Is it happening just for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that two questions were merged. (Also, [Willie said that he merged the questions in the comments...](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-lebesgue-space/51503#comment116276_51502))

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that. Thank you!

Comment: The "most likely"? Are you implying that I sometimes lie? `:-)`

Comment: @Willie: I wrote that at first, and then I saw the comment and edited. The less likely explanation is that MSE is some form of a DeLorean.